# How do I prevent standard users from using the USB ports?

Tags: 12.04

I'm admin for one of my college PC with 3 other normal users . If possible I want to restrict other 3 normal users from using USB. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable USB storage device in Ubuntu, where only root users can only enable it.
Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

[image]

When it opens add blacklist `usb_storage` as the last line, then with the command below 
open the `rc.local` file

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

When it opens, add `modprobe -r usb_storage` before the line exit 0

[image]

Now go ahead and reboot your system.

To mount, open a Terminal and use the following command.

```
sudo modprobe usb_storage
```

To Unmount the USB device, just right click on the device in file manager, and choose safley remove, or Unmount device, and run

```
sudo rmmod usb_storage
```

In Terminal.

<sup>Source: [How to Disable and Enable USB Device](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/how-to-disable-and-enable-usb-device-in-linux/)</sup>

Comment: This disables USB storage system wide in a rather blunt fashion. This is really not the way to do it. Ubuntu uses group permissions for that (see my answer).

Comment: I also had to add `blacklist uas` on Ubuntu 18.04.1 to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

To deny users permission to use USB storage, it should suffice to remove them from the group plugdev.

Comment: See the link "how to disable and enable USB Device"

Comment: oh, i think modprobing around would be perfectly valid for disabeleing USB alltogether, which was the original question, admitted. But isn't the module usb_storage also only for usb volumes? Is i.e. a webcam disabled by removing usb_storage? (It stays operational with my method)

Comment: Oh.. and well the link you posted, it is one method, yes, but a dull one. And it completely ignores modern distributions with polkit setup etc.