# I want to block usb access in ubuntu 11.10 , i have tried it by some codes given before but not working

Tags: installation

In my computer centre in my college ubuntu is installed for some projects purpose in order to keep safe from virus we would like to block pendrive access

Comment: Take a look at this [How do I prevent standard users from using the USB ports?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153964/how-do-i-prevent-standard-users-from-using-the-usb-ports)

Comment: Blocking pen drive access is totally unnecessary and will only get in your students way. The file system has proper permissions unlike windows which prevent things form spreading between users or to the administrator. If you are worried about students using rootkits to gain root access, they don't need a pen drive to do this.
A text editor and c compiler and the code attached to this mailing list email: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.full-disclosure/86747 is all they need if your running an out of date nvidia driver...

Answer (score 0):

1. FS permission solution

   To block:

   ```
   sudo chmod 700 /media
   ```

   To unblock:

   ```
   sudo chmod 755 /media
   ```
2. BIOS option (If available)

   You can also disable USB from system BIOS configuration option. Make sure BIOS is password protected.
3. Grub option

   You can get rid of all USB devices by disabling kernel support for USB via GRUB. Open `grub.conf` or `menu.lst` and append "nousb" to the kernel line as follows:

   ```
   kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-128.1.1 ro root=LABEL=/ console=tty0 console=ttyS1,19200n8 nousb
   ```

   `vmlinuz-2.6.18-128.1.1` - is just an example, put your own

   Save and close the file. Once done just reboot the system:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```