# How to know what had done on my computer?

Tags: log, monitoring

Sometimes other users on my computer use my account. I want to know what did they do on in easy way with GUI. I dont want to read logs and such things.

Are there such tools? If yes, please names.

Comment: You should not let others use your account - just saying. Give them their own account or let them use a guest account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a Tool .

GNOME Activity Journal (formerly known as GNOME Zeitgeist) is a tool for easily browsing and finding files on your computer. It keeps a chronological journal of all file activity and supports tagging and establishing relationships between groups of files.

Open your terminal and type as `sudo apt-get install gnome-activity-journal` to install .

Open your unity dash and type as activity-journal and click it to open .

[image]

Comment: Thanks man its great but is there something more powerful that gives more deep results like inserting USB /CD /DVD ... for example

Comment: @maythux This tool not going to provide such information but you can disable your USB Ports when you want http://askubuntu.com/questions/153964/how-do-i-prevent-standard-users-from-using-the-usb-ports

Comment: Note that, the user can always delete his information with the same tool, even disable it.

Comment: Hi @anwar . well we can change that also as only root can access it . sudo chmod root /path/to application . 

doing from mobile so not able to place link of that question but you can find it from profile questions.

Comment: Yes. but is making it too complicated. I think, just creating a new user profile is the best

Comment: @anwar . . Agree with you brother but what if OP don't want to create another profile .

Comment: @Anwar http://askubuntu.com/questions/193055/how-to-make-some-application-as-only-root-can-access-it/193066#193066 this is the link .:)