# How to make files accessible only by root?

Tags: permissions, root

I'm using Ubuntu and I'm here to know is there any way to modify access of a specific application so that it can only root has access to it?

Currently that application can be launched by general users but I want to make it so that only root can do this.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Make sure that the owner of the application is root and set the permissions such that only the owner can run it.

```
sudo chown root:root /path/to/application
sudo chmod 700 /path/to/application
```

If you look now at permissions with `ls -l /path/to/application`, you should see the following: `-rwx------ root root`, meaning that root can read, write and execute, and anyone else cannot even read that file.

Comment: To find the path to the application, use `which`. For example, `which cat`. It will print the full path to the executable matching the name given.

Comment: @january The part which confuses me, though, is that I can apparently `rm <file>` and it works, even if I am not root.

Comment: Use `sudo chmod 600 /path/to/application` if you don't need execution permissions.

Comment: Note: this doesn't protect you against `rm` if the file is in a directory that is owned by the user. The user (without root) can still remove that file.

Answer (score 9):

Change the permissions of this applications as a root :

```
chmod 700 application-name
```