# Disable access to all USB ports for user account in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: usb, root, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I want to Disable/Restrict access to all usb ports on my PC for user account but allowing access to ROOT! I wonder if some one could help with the instruction to do so with detailed LUI coommand in pattern.

Presently i am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks and Regards 
Anand

Comment: Do you really mean all USB (including keyboards and mice), or just USB storage? The former will be much more difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: Its glad if you could help with both procedures. My requirement with  USB storage Disable!

Comment: You should check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/153964/how-do-i-prevent-standard-users-from-using-the-usb-ports but if it works it will disable all usb i think