# How do I make Ubuntu 14.04 unreachable from physical Ethernet ports?

Tags: 14.04, networking, restricted-access

Suppose that I have files that I'm afraid to even expose to a system that is connected to the Internet. Therefore, I've put them on a separate computer, which **does not** have Wi-Fi or any other sort of Internet connection.

Though, this means that it's still accessible by USB flash drives and it still has Ethernet ports (since that's relevant to my job) which can be used to connect to the Internet. I know [I can disable all USB ports](https://askubuntu.com/a/153999/633367) but can I also disable all networks, the creation of new network connections and any sort of access to the functions that might enable people to do so, unless I need them?

I don't want to deal with ports every time I need to test code or equipment. I already have my firewall configured and don't want to disrupt that. What I'm essentially looking for, is a way to doubly secure the computer. What if I forget to lock my computer and within the five minutes it takes to go to the lock screen someone accesses it? Even if people can access the computer, I don't want them to be able to send **anything out or in** during that time, unless they provide my password.

P.S. The title is about **physical Ethernet ports** where you have to jack a cable in, not the ports that are configured by software inside the computer.

Comment: Use a firewall to close all ports and only them when needed.

Comment: There is also often the possiblity to disable the ethernet ports in the BIOS.

Comment: I already have my ports configured, but I still don't want them open at all times. It would be a pain to override all of my port configuration every time I need to test code or equipment with said computer. If there's a command that can close off all ports at will and then reopen them all when I need to, then that could be useful @George

Comment: use a script with the needed ufw command in it, I use them too to do a lot on my system.

Answer (score 2):

the `ifdown` command can turn off your ethernet adapter.